# How to change color of input with certain value

Tags: jquery

I want to change the color of any input on the page with a value of "--Select--". The following code works on blur:

```
setTimeout(() => {
            $(document).ready(function () {
               $('input').blur(function() {
                    if  ($(this).val().indexOf('Select') !== -1) {
                       $(this).css('color', '#6D6E71');
                    }
                });
            });
}, 500);
```

But since I want to change color of any input with the value "--Select--" on page load, I changed the code to:

```
setTimeout(() => {
                $(document).ready(function () {                
                        if  ($('input').val().indexOf('Select') !== -1) {
                           $(this).css('color', '#6D6E71');
                        }          
                });
 }, 500);
```

This code doesn't work.  Why not?  How should I change it so it will work?  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking all inputs in the `$('input')` collection.
`$('input').val()` will only return the value of the first input in the collection. You can use `each()` in order to iterate over the whole collection:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('input').each(function() {
            if  ($(this).val().indexOf('Select') !== -1) {
               $(this).css('color', '#6D6E71');
            }
        });
    });
}, 500);
```